# Partitions in R-software printed in line with the order of the sizes provided in the input vector

Tags: r, vector, partitioning, combinatorics

Consider the index set {1,..., n}. I would like to find a function in R-software such that it receives a vector of non-negative integers {x[1],..., x[k]} and produces as output a list of all possible partitions of the above-mentioned index set such that the first element of this partition is a set of size x[1], the second element of the partition is a set of size x[2],..., and the k-th element of the partition is a set of size x[k].

I noted the function *listParts* in R-software makes a partition of {1,..., n}. However, that function prints the partitions ordered according to their sizes. Consider the following example:

```
library(partitions)
Aux_9 <- c(2, 3, 1, 3)
P <- listParts(Aux_9)
```

As you can see, *listParts* (and *setparts* as well) provides all possible partitions of the index set {1,..., 9} of the sizes indicated in the input vector. However, for each partition, this function prints its elements in an order in line with their sizes, i.e. following the order (3, 3, 2, 1) and not the order (2, 3, 1, 3).

I was wondering if you could help me to find a function that performs the same as *listParts* in R, but printing the partitions in line with the order of the sizes provided in the components of the input vector, please.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick. Yes. However, I would like that sizes of the elements of each partition are printed in the same order as the order of the components of the input vector in _listParts_ function. I do not know how I can do that. I am sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: a little hard to know how to generalize this.  `P[[1]][c(3,1,4,2)]` (for example) reorders the elements the way you want, but I did the size-matching manually.

Comment: That is a good start. Thank you, @BenBolker.

Comment: A little more generalised: `lapply(P, function(x) x[rev(order(Aux_9,decreasing=T))])`

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help, @Eddie_J.